# How to enable indicators in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, indicator

I'm using an Ubuntu 16.04 image provided by my company.  I'm trying to setup "indicators" so I can see memory usage.

I've searched through here and other resources for steps to enable indicators, but I haven't found anything that works.

I tried installing "gnome-tweaks" and "gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor", but neither of those are found.  I was able to install "indicator-multiload", but it didn't appear to do anything, even after restart.

Comment: What is your desktop environment? GNOME or Unity?

Comment: Are you referring the icon on the top right corner?

Comment: I guess I have Unity.

Comment: @bhordupur I don't understand the question.